# Control not fires DoubleClick event because of code behind another event

Tags: c#, datagrid, double-click

I did not find the answer anywhere, so I'll make new question. I have datagrid, where is some code after SelectionChanged event. And some code on DoubleClick(tried MouseDoubleClick, CellDoubleClick and DoubleClick). On fast PC there is no problem, but on my windows 8 tablet with Intel Atom, where is the app slower, is not fired DoubleClick because of SelectionChange.

If I comment code on SelectionChange, then DoubleClick is fired. But when I leave the code, it seems like it is so slow, that it did not recognize DoubleClick. I have to click realy fast (7-8 times) to fire it.

I thought there is some kind of queue. So that DoubleClick should be fired after SelectionChange at least.

I can't wait after SelectionChange is fired to see if it is not a DoubleClick. Then will look the app slow even on fast pc.

How can be this event lost?

Comment: Have a private member datetime variable and set it in the Selection Change event. Then in single Click event test if its within the time of a DoubleClick and if so fire the DoubleClick event.

Comment: Which UI library are you using? Winforms? WPF? Something else?

Comment: svick: Winforms. Jeremy: Thank you, but I'll probably try to do it in another thread, from szeple or Guvante answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be doing work on the main thread, try using a different thread to do your processing, freeing up your UI thread to receive the double click.

You will need to do some synchronizing, but it should relieve the race condition if done correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do any long calculations in an event handler. I suggest starting a new [thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) (or borrow one from the [threadpool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx), or start a new [task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)), and do the longer running code on a background thread.